# Where to place infinite polling ruby service in a rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Ruby on Rails application, and inside I have a ruby file that has an infinite loop (it does polling for a certain request forever), I need to execute the rails app separately from the ruby app, is there any better way to just fire up the rails app and have the ruby app get executed automatically in a separate process?

Comment: Depends a bit on what the Ruby app actually does, how complex is it? Does it depend on Rails too? How long does one loop take? How often should it run? What should happen if the app fails (auto-restart?)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to wrap this ruby file into a **worker**, and schedule execution every 5s for example and then put it with your Ruby on Rails application.

You can use [Sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq) and [Sidekiq-cron](https://github.com/ondrejbartas/sidekiq-cron)
How to configure cron and sidekiq-cron you can find in their original repos.
Configuration example for sidekiq-cron below.

```yaml
my_ruby_worker:
  every: 5s
  class: SomeWorker
  queue: High
  description: Schedules some actions inside plain ruby file
```

Comment: Will that work? the ruby file is doing a constant polling job in an infinite loop, won't cancelling it over and over again might not work properly?

Comment: what is polling? It is an operation that does the same thing with *some* timeout, I don't see your code, but if you need to store some state between different pollings that may not work, however one should not store some state between pollings, cause it violates independency of that operation. If your case to ask for something and then store it in some storage db/file etc that will perfectly fit your needs.

Comment: I am using a package called `telegram-bot-ruby` and the package has a wrapped function called `run` that infinitely runs, you can find the package [here](https://github.com/atipugin/telegram-bot-ruby)

Comment: for this case, I would treat it as other application, and would deploy it separately. Cause it just for now it is single file, but afterwards it will get bigger as your implementation grows